# Opening ArcGIS portal item in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-portal, pitem

I am trying to use a transport layer in ArcMap. I have sourced it from the NSW Spatial Catalogue (https://portal.spatial.nsw.gov.au/portal/home/item.html?id=66fabd8c23074ecc85883e0086419adc) but I can only download it as a Portal Item which I have never worked with before.

I have tried 'add data' and dragging the item into ArcMap but nothing happens.

How do I add this layer in ArcMap (ArcGIS Desktop)?

I am a beginner when it comes to GIS!

Answer (score 4):

I too could not get the Portal Item to load into ArcMap. I have to admit they are not something I am familiar with. But you can still access the data by adding it as a web service. On the web page you link to click on the copy button next to the URL to copy it.

[image: URL]

Then in ArcMap go to catalog window click on GIS Servers > Add ArcGIS Server and select Use GIS Service.  In the Server URL, simply paste the copied URL and press finish.

[image: Adding Server]

You will now have access to all the layers to drag 'n' drop into your map.

[image: Services]

Or alternatively click on the obvious **Export Data** button at the top of the Description...

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open a ArcGIS File Handler, or ArcGIS Portal Item, extension of the ".pitem" type. The ArcGIS File Handler utility lets you start a new application, or add the layer to an open application, when you double-click it in Windows Explorer. [More details here](https://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisexplorer/2500/en/add_arcgis_layers.htm).

So, just double-click it and an ArcGis Desktop window will pop-up asking you to provide your ArcGIS Online details. Then, if everything is right, the layer will appear on your Table of Contents on ArcGIS Desktop.